# Location of profile directory of XUL app

Tags: sqlite, firefox, xul, xulrunner

I'm creating a desktop app using Mozilla's XUL. I created an SQLite database, and stored some data in it. The database was created using:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["tickets.sqlite"]);
var dbConn = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
```

I tested if the tables really exist using `tableExists` method, and I got `true` message. The database should be stored in the profile directory, which is by default located in a hidden folder (I use Fedora, by the way) in the home directory: `~/.mozilla/`. Problem is I can't find my database there, stored as `tickets.sqlite`. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you got a file you can definitively retrieve its path using properties `path`, `nativePath` etc. - dump it onto console for example.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFile for more details about nsIFile.

Answer (score 0):

Profile directory appears in app cache, for Linux it is in the home folder, and it's a hidden folder(not sure for WIN). Cache's name is defined in application.spec file, where you define Vendor name and App name, so cache folder is going to be .Vendor and inside it you will find App folder with details. That is the profile dir for Mozilla apps.